# send mail from other configuration if first config fails laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to create a code such that if one configuration fails to send mail the other config will kick in to send the mail, I have created two configurations, One in the provider which is set on page load the other is a helper function which can be set as we need. 
if I set the helper function before sending any mail the function kicks in but if I keep it in try-catch block the helper doesn't work

```
try {
          Mail::to($administrator->email)->send(new ResetPassword($data));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
          $mailsenderr = true;
        }
        if ($mailsenderr) {
          $newConfig = new SecondaryMailer;
          $newConfig->setmailer();
          try {
            Mail::to($administrator->email)->send(new ResetPassword($data));
          } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return [
              "status" => 0,
              "message" => 'Error sending mail.'
              // , "error" => $e->getMessage()
            ];
          }
        }
        return ["status" => 1, "message" => "Mail sent successflly"];
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  For example when you test if email sent and fail just execute the second config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to
Just create a provider and set the code like

```
$mail = DB::table('mail_variables')->where('mailer_type', 'primary')->where('status', 'active')->first();
        try {
            $transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport($mail->host, $mail->port, $mail->encryption);
            $transport->setUsername($mail->username);
            $transport->setPassword($mail->password);
            $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
            $mailer->getTransport()->start();
        } catch (\Swift_TransportException  $e) {
            $mail = DB::table('mail_variables')->where('mailer_type', 'secondary')->where('status', 'active')->first();
        }
        $config = array(
            'driver'      => $mail->driver,
            'host'        => $mail->host,
            'port'        => $mail->port,
            'from'        => array(
                'address'   => $mail->from_address,
                'name'      => $mail->from_name
            ),
            'encryption'  => $mail->encryption,
            'username'    => $mail->username,
            'password'    => $mail->password,
            'sendmail'    => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            'pretend'     => false,
        );
        Config::set('mail', $config);
```